# best way to have html5 form elements in Yii form

Tags: html, forms, yii

I need to have some special html5 form elements like **range** , **number** and ... in Yii Form.

What is the best and clearest way to implement them in my forms?

Comment: I am not aware of any difference in Yii for the implementation of HTML5 elements as opposed to other, older elements. Simply put them in your view...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are supported by CHtml since 1.1.11, eg.

- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeEmailField-detail
- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeNumberField-detail